# Very challenging interpretation

Tags: meaning-in-context

It's a very difficult question I am gonna ask from Charles Dickens' A tales of two cities.

**Mrs. Southcott had recently attained her five-and-twentieth blessed birthday, of whom a prophetic private in the Life Guards had heralded the sublime appearance by announcing that arrangements were made for the swallowing up of London and Westminster**.

what does this part of the sentence mean **"of whom a prophetic private in the Life Guards had heralded the sublime appearance"**

I know it's a tough question- ppl will complain  random things about the post rather than answering it. But thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here goes: It seems there is a real historical person by the name of Joanna Southcott. Her dates are 1750-1814, and her website is [JoannaSouthcott.com](http://www.joannasouthcott.com/true.htm).

She had many followers during her lifetime who believed she was a prophetess, messenger of God, etc.

I believe that this is the "Mrs. Southcott" referred to by Charles Dickens in this very dense passage.

> Mrs. Southcott had recently attained her five-and-twentieth blessed
>   birthday,

I think what Dickens means to say here is that Mrs. Southcott was at that time 25 yrs. old, and had recently had a birthday. [Not sure why he calls it a "blessed birthday", except maybe to emphasize her self-proclaimed holiness.]

Now for the part you ask about:

> of whom a prophetic private in the Life Guards had heralded the
>   sublime appearance

"Whom" here refers back (before the discussion of the birthday) to Mrs. Southcott herself. So Dickens is explaining how her "sublime appearance" [i.e. her birth, when she "appeared" on Earth] was accompanied by a prophecy by a someone who was a private [rank] in the [Life Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_Guards_(United_Kingdom)) [regiment].

The word order in this part of the sentence is a little convoluted, but I think you could re-order it like this: "A prophetic private in the Life Guards had heralded the sublime appearance of [Mrs. S.]"

The story goes on to state the content of that soldier's prophecy -- that some calamity was to happen to London and Westminster.

However, judging from the next few sentences in the book, I get the feeling that the details of this particular sentence you are asking about aren't critical to the rest of the book, but just a way to set the scene and the tone. Could be wrong though, since I didn't ever read the book.